# LaTex symbol that I am not sure about

Tags: latex, symbols

I am not sure how to write this symbol in LaTeX. Can someone kindly tell?
the closest symbol that I found was `\mathfrak{P}` but that doesn't work for me.

[image: symbol...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `\mathfrak{p}` you will need to include `\usepackage{amssymb}` in the preamble of the document.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
   \mathfrak{p}
\end{document}
```

If that is not the correct symbol, where is the symbol from?  What does it stand for?  You may be able to use [the Detexify tool](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to find the right one.  You will notice that Detexify will tell you which package is necessary to include to produce the symbol.

Answer (score -1):

My bad. Its \mathfrak{p}. Not \mathfrak{P}. :D